# Robocopy based on extensions

Tags: python, robocopy

Currently I am using robocopy in python to copy out files based on extensions.

The code is below:

```
call(["robocopy","C:\",dest,"*.7z","/S","/COPYALL"])
```

But in a scenario where there is no 7z files, it still creates the dest directory.

Is there a way to only create the directory and copy the file only if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not check if there are 7z files before calling the copy utility?

```
import glob
if glob.glob("*.7z"):
   call(["robocopy","C:\",dest,"*.7z","/S","/COPYALL"])
```